# My sister and I keep switching skins in minecraft!

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I play minecraft(bedrock edition, version 1.14.60) together using LAN(local are network). but whenever we join each other's worlds, we swap skins! We are both using the custom skin, where we both make our own skins, but we always show up with each other's skins. What do I do? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [unresolved bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-48207).

Please consider researching the topic a little more before you post here. In this case, you can find the linked page on the 1st result by searching `minecraft bedrock skins switching` on any simple search engine.

I understand that you did do some more research on the topic, and that you have found items talking about the bug but not fixing it. In that case, I would just like to confirm that no, there is no current fix, I'm afraid. You'll just have to go on without it. I'm terribly sorry about this bug.

Comment: yeah, but I have searched it and tried to fix it. It never works, not even restarting minecraft.

Comment: Well you can't fix it. You need to wait for the devteam on the backend to fix it. In the meantime, there's nothing you can do. If it's open and unresolved, chances are, nothing on your end will fix it!

Comment: ok. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: In the meantime, you'll just have to wait it out, and deal with what you've got. Too bad, I'm afraid! Hopefully the devteam will fix it soon.